# Why the letter q for the line equation y = mx + q? Is it used only in Italian?

Tags: etymology, mathematics

I realized that in my code I am using the letter *q* for the axis intercept, while my non Italian colleagues use the letter *b* or *n* (luckily for the slope we all use *m*).

Is the use of *q* specific to Italian? Where does it come from?

Interestingly I found some old discussions about the etymology of *m* ([1](https://services.math.duke.edu/education/webfeats/Slope/Slopederiv.html), [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20171117013050/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65307.html), [3](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226054916/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52477.html)), but the conclusion is that the choice may have been arbitrary.

Comment: Veramente curioso. In catalano ho sempre visto *n* o *b* (indistintamente) (stavo per mettere i simboli $ $ alle lettere *n* e *b* :).

Comment: Could you add a source for _q_? As an Italian mathematician, personally I'd spontaneously write _y_ = _ax_ + _b_.

Comment: That's how I learnt in school:  y = mx + q or ax + by + c = 0 . A search for y =mx+ q in Google has only Italian results, for example http://www-dimat.unipv.it/atorre/CTF2011-12/Rette.pdf

Comment: Just a half-baked idea: q suggests in some area of mathematics a quoziente (Italian for ratio). So, since when going from an implicit form ( _f_ (_x_, _y_)=0) to an explicit one ( _y_ =...) the intercept's ordinate is obtained as a ratio of other terms, someone might have chosen that letter for this reason. But, as I said, I am not familiar with this notation.

Comment: Anche a me l'unica cosa che mi ricorda *q* è quoziente, però se vogliamo vederla così la pendenza dovrebbe chiamarsi *q* a maggior ragione... Sono sorpresa che questa notazione non sia univoca neanche in Italia! Ho posto la domanda in inglese sperando che qualcuno mi potesse rispondere "Anche da me nel paese <> si dice così", ma ho ottenuto la risposta opposta! :)

Comment: Io ho molto spesso trovato _y = mx + p_ ma cercando in rete sembra una notazione presente nei testi in lingua francese.

Comment: Per curiosità, @laika, dove hai chiesto la domanda in inglese?

Comment: Vedete questo [elenco](https://www.mathsisfun.com/equation_of_line.html#Countrynote) di notazioni per l'equazione di una retta (non verticale) in forma esplicita per diversi paesi, è veramente curioso. A quanto pare, *q* per l'ordinata all'origine si usa in effetti soltanto in Italia.

Comment: Su questo [sito web](http://www.edutecnica.it/matematica/retta/retta.htm) ho trovato che *q* viene da "quota". Ma perché "quota"?

Comment: Anche [qui](http://www.bordin.biz/domir1819/220/retta.pdf) si afferma che *q*  rappresenta la "quota a cui la retta interseca l'asse verticale".

Comment: Non conosco il vocabolario di matematica in italiano, quindi veramente non capisco cosa sia questa "quota".

Comment: Il [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI15/00179.jpg) riporta questa accezione per "quota": "Altezza  dal  suolo  di  un  punto,  di  un  oggetto, di una persona, ecc.". E anche: "Distanza  di  un  punto  da  un  piano  orizzon­tale,  alla  quale  si  attribuisce  il  valore  negativo  o positivo  a  seconda  che  il  punto  sia  al  di  sopra  o al di sotto del piano stesso".

Comment: Sì, @Charo, “quota” potrebbe riferirsi a questo senso. Nel linguaggio comune si usa molto, per esempio, per parlare dell'altezza a cui volano gli aerei (anche se è più preciso usare appunto “altezza” rispetto al suolo in un dato momento e “altitudine” rispetto al livello del mare). Qui, quindi, “altezza” sopra l'origine degli assi.

Comment: @Charo Credo che potrebbe essere un'eccellente risposta (un po' speculativa magari, ma con questa domanda dubito che si possa fare molto meglio purtroppo).

Comment: @Charo ho fatto la domanda solo qui, però ho scelto di farla in inglese invece che in italiano sperando fosse più accessibile.

Comment: Ah, ho capito, @laika! Credi conveniente una traduzione della risposta in inglese? (in teoria avrei dovuto rispondere in inglese)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questo [sito web](https://www.mathsisfun.com/equation_of_line.html#Countrynote) riporta un elenco di notazioni per l'equazione di una retta (non verticale) in forma esplicita per diversi paesi. A quanto pare, *q* per l'ordinata all'origine si usa in effetti soltanto in Italia.

Parecchi siti web chiamano "quota" il parametro *q*, per esempio, [questo](http://www.edutecnica.it/matematica/retta/retta.htm), [questo](http://www.bordin.biz/domir1819/220/retta.pdf), in cui si afferma che *q*  rappresenta la "quota a cui la retta interseca l'asse verticale", e persino il sito di [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/m/Px62g5Au).

Quindi, *q* potrebbe venire dal termine "quota" con queste accezioni tratte dal [*Grande dizionario della lingua  italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI15/00179.jpg):

> Altezza  dal  suolo  di  un  punto,  di  un  oggetto, di una persona, ecc.

> Distanza  di  un  punto  da  un  piano  orizzon­tale,  alla  quale  si  attribuisce  il  valore  negativo  o positivo  a  seconda  che  il  punto  sia  al  di  sopra  o al di sotto del piano stesso.

Comment: Ho appena visto che sul [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI15/00179.jpg) appare una definizione di "quota" apparteniente al campo della geometria: "*Quota di un punto*: nel metodo delle proiezioni, la distanza del punto dal quadro". Il problema è che non riesco a capire del tutto bene cosa sia "il metodo delle proiezioni" (potrebbe includere la proiezione ortogonale di un punto su una retta?) e non ho idea di cosa significhi "quadro". Come ho detto in un commento precedente, non conosco il vocabolario italiano di matematica perché non sono italiana.

Comment: "La distanza di un punto (o di un oggetto, elemento, ente) da un piano orizzontale prefissato di riferimento, alla quale si attribuisce il segno + o − secondo che il punto sia al disopra o al disotto del piano stesso." — da [qui](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/quota).

Comment: Il quadro: "In geometria descrittiva, il piano, o uno dei piani, sopra il quale si esegue la rappresentazione piana delle figure spaziali." — da [qui](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/quadro2/).

Comment: [Anchissimo](https://books.google.ru/books?id=jVkG7NFxtLQC&pg=RA11-PA3&lpg=RA11-PA3&dq=il+quadro+geometria&source=bl&ots=tg1KGWfLGk&sig=ACfU3U1YcBfa8oE13_3VmrT12B8r92-DNw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGr5-GlL3oAhVJkMMKHX39BA0Q6AEwCnoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=il%20quadro%20geometria&f=false) (voglio usare questa parola, si vuol che mi lasci fare!). Infatti credo il GDLI debba aver una preferenza per le idee antiche. Può darsi che parzialmente anche in questo caso…

Comment: @Evgeniy: Penso che questo "quadro" antichissimo sia semplicemente un quadrato.

Comment: Infatti il congiuntivo è eccessivo, è molto chiaro che sia un quadrato in quel libro. :) C'è una somiglianza fra il significato della geometria proiettiva e quello di un quadrato. Una somiglianza che era opportuna per quell'epoca, ma non per la nostra.

Comment: Sì, @Evgeniy: si tratta chiarissimamente di un quadrato.

Comment: Non capisco perché lo dici, ma lasciamolo stare…